# Create a hover area that doesn't consume click events

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, mouseevent

I want to display a tooltip box upon hovering on an element, and I only want the tooltip to disappear once the user's mouse exits a custom hover area as defined by a vector graphic.

This works except that the hover area blocks click events from bubbling up to the tooltip, as shown below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hover-me").mouseenter(function(e) {
    $("#mouse-box").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#tooltip").show();
  });
  $("#mouse-box").mouseleave(function(e) {
    $("#mouse-box").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $("#tooltip").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  display: none;
  height: 60px;
}

#hover-me {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 140px;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 210px;
  height: 83px;
  opacity: 0.03;
  pointer-events: none;
}

svg clipPath rect:first-child {
  width: 90px;
  height: 100%;
  x: 0;
  y: 0;
}

svg clipPath rect:last-child {
  width: 130px;
  height: 35px;
  x: 90px;
  y: 25px;
}

#mouse-box {
  fill: red;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="tooltip">Can't click</button>
<div id="hover-me">Hover me</div>
<svg>
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="clip">
        <rect/><rect/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <rect id="mouse-box" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Have you considered not using an HTML button? And instead using an SVG button in your tooltip?

Comment: I'm not actually using a button in my real tooltip. I have one in the example here because it quickly demonstrates not being able to click. Basic things like clicking links and highlighting text also do not work.

Comment: So you want a tooltip that is visible, but is transparent to all mouse events - other than `mouseleave`?

Comment: Not quite. I have a tooltip and a hover area. The hover area should be transparent to all mouse events other than `mouseleave`. In this example, I've highlighted the hover area to visualize what's going on.

Comment: That's what I meant. Your hover area is effectively part of your tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a `z-index` to the tooltip to make it render on top of the hover area.

However, the hover area's `mouseleave` handler started firing whenever the mouse entered the tooltip, causing it to become hidden.

To get around this, I added `if ($('#tooltip:hover').length === 0)` to the `mouseleave` handler so that I only hide the tooltip if the mouse exits the hover area via its outside perimeter.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hover-me").mouseenter(function(e) {
    $("#mouse-box").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#tooltip").show();
  });
  $("#mouse-box").mouseleave(function(e) {
    if ($('#tooltip:hover').length === 0) {
      $("#mouse-box").css("visibility", "hidden");
      $("#tooltip").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  display: none;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 10;
}

#hover-me {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 140px;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 210px;
  height: 83px;
  opacity: 0.03;
  pointer-events: none;
}

svg clipPath rect:first-child {
  width: 90px;
  height: 100%;
  x: 0;
  y: 0;
}

svg clipPath rect:last-child {
  width: 130px;
  height: 35px;
  x: 90px;
  y: 25px;
}

#mouse-box {
  fill: red;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="tooltip">Can click</button>
<div id="hover-me">Hover me</div>
<svg>
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="clip">
        <rect/><rect/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <rect id="mouse-box" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have trouble getting all mouse events functioning, but for `click()`, at least, you can use the hide-test-show-click trick.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hover-me").mouseenter(function(e) {
    $("#mouse-box").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#tooltip").show();
  });
  $("#mouse-box").mouseleave(function(e) {
    $("#mouse-box").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $("#tooltip").hide();
  });

  $("#mouse-box").click(function(e) {
    $("#mouse-box").hide();
    var elem = document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    $("#mouse-box").show();
    $(elem).click();
  });
  
  $("#tooltip").click(function(e) {
    alert("Clicked!");
  });
});
```

```css
#tooltip {
  display: none;
  height: 150px;
}

#hover-me {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  left: 140px;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 210px;
  height: 150px;
  opacity: .03;
  pointer-events: none;
}

svg clipPath rect:first-child {
  width: 70px;
  height: 670px;
  x: 0;
  y: 0;
}

svg clipPath rect:last-child {
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  x: 70px;
  y: 50px;
}

#mouse-box {
  fill: red;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="tooltip">Tooltip</button>
<div id="hover-me">Hover me</div>
<svg>
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="clip">
        <rect/><rect/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <rect id="mouse-box" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: This doesn't allow for simple things like text selection, link navigation, click animations, etc.

Comment: I think it's the closest you are going to get.